# Python: find consecutive values in 3D numpy array without using groupby?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, probability, python-itertools

Say that you have the following 3D numpy array:

```
matrices=
numpy.array([[[1, 0, 0], #Level 0
              [1, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1]],

             [[0, 1, 0], #Level 1
              [1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]],

             [[0, 0, 1], #Level 2
              [0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1]]])
```

And that you want to compute the number of times you get consecutive values of 1 for each cell. Let's say you want to count the number of occurrences of 2 and 3 consecutive values of 1 for each cell. The result should be something like this:

```
two_cons=([[0,0,0],
           [1,1,0],
           [0,0,0]])
three_cons=([[0,0,0],
             [0,1,0],
             [0,0,0]])
```

meaning that two cells have had at least 2 consecutive values of 1, and only one has had 3 consecutive values.

I know this could be done by using `groupby`, extracting the "vertical" series of values for each cell, and counting how many times you get `n` consecutive ones:

```
import numpy
two_cons=numpy.zeros((3,3))
for i in range(0,matrices.shape[0]): #Iterate through each "level"
    for j in range(0,matrices.shape[1]):
        vertical=matrices[:,i,j] #Extract the series of 0-1 for each cell of the matrix
        #Determine the occurrence of 2 consecutive values
        cons=numpy.concatenate([numpy.cumsum(c) if c[0] == 1 else c for c in numpy.split(vertical, 1 + numpy.where(numpy.diff(vertical))[0])])
        two_cons[i][j]=numpy.count_nonzero(cons==2)
```

In this example, you get that:

```
two_cons=
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

**My question: how can I do this if I cannot access *vertical*?** In my real case, the 3D numpy array is too large for me to extract vertical series across many levels, so I have to loop through each level at once, and kind of keep memory of what happened at the previous `n` levels. What do you suggest to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked the code, but something like this should work... the idea is to scan the matrix along the third dimension and have 2 helper matrices, one keeping track of the length of the actual sequence of ones, and one keeping track of the best sequence encountered so far.

```
bests = np.zeros(matrices.shape[:-1])
counter = np.zeros(matrices.shape[:-1])

for depth in range(matrices.shape[0]):
    this_level = matrices[depth, :, :]
    counter = counter * this_level + this_level
    bests = (np.stack([bests, counter], axis=0)).max(axis=0)

two_con = bests > 1
three_con = bests > 2
```

Comment: This line is problematic: `for depth in len(matrices.shape[-1]):`. What did you want to do here?

Comment: sorry, range() instead of len()

Comment: And now something else: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. I think it refers to `bests = (np.stack(bests, counter)).max(axis=2)`.

Comment: probably it is because I had the syntax of `np.stack` wrong... try it now!

Comment: I don't think this gives what I expect. For example, `two_con` should be `array([[0.,  0.,  0.],[1.,  1.,  0.],[0.,  0.,  0.]])`, while with this snippet I get `array([[0.,  1.,  1.],[0.,  1.,  0.],[0.,  1.,  0.]])`. They don't match even if you transpose `two_con`.

Comment: ok, that's because I got the wrong axes to scan... (2 instead of 0) I changed it  and checked, it should work now